# naming conventions for MTT topics?

Tags: mqtt, iot

(I'm posting here on the advice on the https://mqtt.org/faq/ page, even though I know that "style" questions are frowned upon.  Bear with me...)

Is there a general convention for naming MQTT **topics**?  In particular, consider these three cases in an IOT device that has a set of relays.  Note that the relays may not change at the moment that they are asked to:

1. payload contains a request to set the relays to a given state.  (subscribed to by the relay module)
2. payload contains the current state of the relays (published by the relay module when a relay changes)
3. payload is empty, message is a request to report the current state of the relays (published by anyone who wants fresh info on relay state)

What would you name the topic for the three cases above?  Without knowing any of the conventions, I would imagine something like:

- relay/set_state
- relay/state
- relay/request_state

... but I defer to folks more deeply steeped in the MQTT lore than I am.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think much has changed since [this answer](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/2733) on `iot.stackexchange.com`. There are some [additional opinions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/designing-mqtt-topics-aws-iot-core/mqtt-design-best-practices.html) and [standards](https://sparkplug.eclipse.org/) but I'm not sure about adoption rates... The lack of a widely accepted standard does make this somewhat opinion based but also gives you the freedom to pick the topic structure that best fits your needs.

Comment: Point 3 is redundant, use retained messages

Answer (score 0):

As noted elsewhere there is no single "best practice".

This may be a later addition to the MQTT standard but MQTT5 does include a "[response topic](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901114)" optional field in the PUBLISH message.  It's presence there is specifically for [Request/Response use cases](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Request_/_Response).

I would only have the `relay/state` if you expect the relay to simply send out its current state periodically without it being requested.

If the only time the relate sends its state is in response to a request then either the request should contain the topic and correlation data to be used in the response.  If using MQTT5 then this can go in the message properties, otherwise this could be included in the message payload.

That leaves just two.  It's your call whether you want informative requests (tell me your state) and instruction requests (do this) to be on separate channels.  My own disposition on this matter is to keep them separate because its always good to be able to listen to instructions without noise.

Answer (score -1):

If you search for "mqtt topic name conventions", or "mqtt topic names best practices", you will find some ideas.

e.g:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/designing-mqtt-topics-aws-iot-core/mqtt-design-best-practices.html
- https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-8-retained-messages/
- https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-8-retained-messages/